# In django, how can I include some default records in my models.py?

Tags: database, django, django-models

If I have a models.py like

```
class WidgetType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Widget(models.Model):
     typeid = models.ForeignKey(WidgetType)
     data = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How can I build in a set of built in constant values for `WidgetType` when I know I'm only going to have a certain few types of widget?  Clearly I could fire up my admin interface and add them by hand, but I'd like to simplify configuration by having it built into the python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use fixtures:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

Strictly speaking, fixtures aren't part of the models, or any python code for that matter. If you really need it in your python code, you could listen for the [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal and insert your data through the ORM, e.g.:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

def insert_initial_data(sender, app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
    if WidgetType in created_models:
        for name in ('widgettype1', 'widgettype2', 'widgettype3'):
            WidgetType.objects.get_or_create(name=name)

post_migrate.connect(insert_initial_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `Migration` and insert new records (or do any other migration you want).

See [this article item](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) in `Django` docs.

Comment: This seems like the perfect solution for the use case. Thanks.